# Session locking on MVC ASP.Net - Preventing users from accessing the same resource at the same time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a query that I am unsure about.
I am in the middle of developing an MVC Web App for a client, the app manages content in an XML document stored in SQL.

When a users accesses the XML document, it is copied to session where any changes the user makes are made, before being properly committed back to DB when a save changes event is triggered.

The client has requested that there be a lock in place to prevent other users from accessing/modifying the XML content if another user is already accessing it.

Firstly, I'm not even sure how to implement such a feature or how you would decide if a session is active or not, or whether save timeouts should apply (but ultimately annoy users who take a long time to make changes), but more than that I personally think that their reasoning for having it is not strong enough to warrant it, given the extreme deadline we are dealing with.

Their reason is that their current solution "does it", so should the new.
However their current solution is based on an entirely different platform and I don't think the client understands what it is they are asking for - as it may end up being more of a hindrance than not.

What is other peoples opinions on this and has anyone dealt with similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just lock the record with a bit field?

Add a boolean flag to the database record, e.g. `RecordInUse`.

When a user views the xml content, set the flag. When the user end their access to the record, unset the flag.

Whenever somebody wants to view the xml, check if the flag is set or not before allowing access.

You'll just need to figure out how to handle the scenario when people close the browser.

Comment: Yes, a flag like this makes sense. However, that is not what the singleton pattern means.

Comment: @Jacob yeah sorry for that, will remove the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a few things to make the system more user-friendly

**1. Write Access to Xml**  - Use a simple bit field to lock the document

**2. Readonly access** - If the document is locked, notify users and allow them to view the document in read only mode.

**3. Who is editing** - A separate table to hold who is editing information (more info in 6.)

**4. Contact current editor** - Send an email alert to request current editor to save and exit.

**5. Admin level override** - Current editor is not contactable,reset lock boolean. Roll-back his changes (drafts) if necessary.

**6. Draft save and final save** - In 3. we mentioned about a separate table to hold who is editing information. You can use the same table to save draft copies. So the editor can save and continue. Only the final save should override the original xml in your main table.

All the above scenarios are not that difficult to implement. For an example google docs has a very complicated web based document editor. I do not think you will have to think that far or, do anything as complicated as that.